# Homestead .htaccess rewrite rule with Angular 7

Tags: angular, .htaccess, homestead

I tried to use the `Homestead` with my Angular project, and when I press refresh in browser on an URI (what is acually doesn't exists) the RewriteRule doesn't catch the request and isn't redirect to the `index.html` file where the Angular can handle the URI.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

I always get `No input file specified.` message if refresh on a route. On the main path (www.example.test/) the index.html file is loading well.

What is the correct .htaccess configuration to this case? Or if not the .htaccess is the problem where can I check other settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

My Homestead run with `Nginx` http server, so the .htaccess file is ignored.

So I need to edit the config file under the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.test` file, update with this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    // this is what I added:
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
    }
}
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tried, but unfortunately isn't helped.

Comment: Are you running both Homestead  & Angular together

Comment: It might be that .htaccess of both is conflicting.

Comment: You can put Homestead in a different folder